# VF with long:out within SImpleDialog iFrame in classic console - Cant close or refresh tab

Tags: visualforce, javascript, console, iframe, lightning-out

I have some legacy code that works everywhere except it is now broken in Salesforce Classic Sales Console.

The code is executed from a javascript button that put the content of a VF page within an iframe

**Button code**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/38.0/apex.js")} {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js")}     


var sd;
var iframesize;
var isscroll;
if (document.documentElement.clientHeight > 833) {
    iframesize = 833;
    isscroll = "no";
} else {
    iframesize = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 100;
    isscroll = "yes";
}

function createDialog() {
    sd = new SimpleDialog("Dialog", true);    
    sd.setWidth(655);
    sd.setTitle('<h2 id="title">Payment Console</h2>');
    sd.createDialog();
    window.parent.sd = sd;
    document.body.setAttribute("style", "overflow: hidden;");
    var iframe_url = '{!URLFOR("/apex/THEVFPAGE", null, [id = Account.Id ,accId = Account.Id])}';
    sd.setContentInnerHTML('<iframe id="iframeContentId" src="' + iframe_url + '" frameborder="0" height="' + iframesize + '" width="630" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" align="center" scrolling="' + isscroll + '" style="overflow-y: hidden !important; overflow-x: hidden !important;" />');
}

function setElements() {
    try {
        document.getElementById("DialogContent").style.overflowY = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("DialogContent").style.overflowX = "hidden";
        document.getElementsByClassName("bottomRight")[1].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("Dialog").style.overflow = "auto";
    } catch (e) {}
}

function showDialog() {
    if (window.parent.sd == undefined) {
        createDialog();
        sd.show();
    } else {
        window.parent.sd.show();
    }
    setElements();
}


showDialog();
```

From what I can tell this uses some legacy salesforce SimpleDialog javascript to place a modal window over the standard salesforce record page.

The Visualforce page uses `lng:out` to display a lightning component

Within that visualforce page I am capturing the `force:navigateToURL` event and I navigate to the standard record page

**The problem**

When in Salesforce Classic Console it will no longer let me redirect back to the standard record page as the code is currently....

**VF Aura Handler (unimportant parts redacted)**

```
$A.eventService.addHandler({
   event: 'force:navigateToURL',
   handler: function (event) {

   window.parent.location.href = '/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}';
});
```

I get the error:

> [Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': The current window
>   does not have permission to navigate the target frame to
>   '/0018A00000N9JdW'.]

I tried using the `integration.js` to get the enclosing tab etc but everything returns null from within the iframe.

**Questions**

How can I either refresh's the browser `'/console'` URL so the SimpleDialog is removed or is there another way I can either access the calling JS to execute a function or something to either refresh the current tab or window or close the dialog?

Basically I cannot find a way to close the SimpleDialog or refresh's the current console tab from within the iframe

Appreciate any insight, pointers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using `postMessage`. When I tried before I did not have the `"*"` as the domain parameter and that was blocking me.

I added this to the JS Button

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event){
    if( event.data === "close"){
        window.parent.sd = null; //Needed due to current code. Assignment to window.parent.sd in old code should probably be removed but....
        sd.cancel(); //Close
        location.reload(); //reload the tab
    }
}
```

Then on the VF page I simply do this:

```
window.parent.postMessage('close','*');
```